# How to set the srting in to key value pairs

Tags: php, string

How to split the string in to key value pairs to insert in to database

jsonis=`{"foe_tat":"08:33:00","stateId":"up","uid":"17","comment":"","caseId":"mMJjyqPsVK","applicantId":"0","photo":"","questions":"{34=[{rem=, ans=No}], 46=[{rem=, ans=gbo}], 48=[{rem=, ans=NA}], 29=[{rem=, ans=No}], 45=[{rem=, ans=gfi}], 49=[{rem=, ans=Non Serviceable}], 43=[{rem=, ans=1 BHK}], 35=[{rem=, ans=Society Board}], 38=[{rem=, ans=gghi}], 39=[{rem=, ans=fcdr}], 27=[{rem=, ans=ffji}], 41=[{rem=, ans=Others}], 52=[{rem=test remark 2, ans=ggivvju}], 47=[{rem=Test remarks for feedback, ans=ggijcf}], 31=[{rem=, ans=Chawl}], 37=[{rem=, ans=Self Owned}], 33=[{rem=, ans=Others}], 30=[{rem=, ans=gfhi}], 50=[{rem=, ans=gcogv}], 51=[{rem=test remarks, ans=gcgicd}], 32=[{rem=, ans=NA}], 44=[{rem=, ans=[Refrigerator, Airconditioner]}]}"}`

I want only for questions array

```
$string=
"34={rem=1, ans=No},
 46={rem=2, ans=hddg}, 
 48={rem=a, ans=NA}, 
 29={rem=s, ans=Yes}, 
 45={rem=d, ans=gydg}, 
 49={rem=f, ans=InConclusive},
 43={rem=g, ans=1 BHK},
 35={rem=q, ans=Society Board},
 38={rem=r, ans=34},
 39={rem=6, ans=9},
 27={rem=6, ans=yes},
 41={rem=6, ans=Others}, 
 52={rem=test remark 2, ans=gifvkj},
 47={rem=Test remarks for feedback, ans=hhgghi}, 
 31={rem=6, ans=Slum}, 
 37={rem=6, ans=Self Owned}, 
 33={rem=6, ans=Village}, 
 30={rem=6, ans=gjhxfh}, 
 50={rem=6, ans=gifxhj}, 
 51={rem=test remarks, ans=tdjigf}, 
 32={rem=6, ans=NA},
 44={rem=6, ans=[Refrigerator, Airconditioner, Television]}";
```

expected output

```
key=34 rem=1 ans=no
key=46 rem=2 ans=hddg
key=48 rem=a ans=NA
```

so on ..
using any loop

Comment: As you can see your code has a pattern and it is a string not a json

Comment: Where's the string coming from? Is there any reason it's in this homebrew format? Could you use proper JSON or YAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$string="";//your string
$string=str_replace("]}","]",$string);
$arr=explode("},",str_replace("={rem=",",",$string));

foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
    $str=explode(",",$value);
    $data[$key]["key"] = intval($str[0]);
    $data[$key]["rem"] = $str[1];
    $data[$key]["ans"] = explode("ans=", $value)[1];
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bb2a5eebbe6ad2d4824c84514f86d99091ac1379)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$string=
"34={rem=1, ans=No},
 46={rem=2, ans=hddg}, 
 48={rem=a, ans=NA}, 
 29={rem=s, ans=Yes}, 
 45={rem=d, ans=gydg}, 
 49={rem=f, ans=InConclusive},
 43={rem=g, ans=1 BHK},
 35={rem=q, ans=Society Board},
 38={rem=r, ans=34},
 39={rem=6, ans=9},
 27={rem=6, ans=yes},
 41={rem=6, ans=Others}, 
 52={rem=test remark 2, ans=gifvkj},
 47={rem=Test remarks for feedback, ans=hhgghi}, 
 31={rem=6, ans=Slum}, 
 37={rem=6, ans=Self Owned}, 
 33={rem=6, ans=Village}, 
 30={rem=6, ans=gjhxfh}, 
 50={rem=6, ans=gifxhj}, 
 51={rem=test remarks, ans=tdjigf}, 
 32={rem=6, ans=NA},
 44={rem=6, ans=[Refrigerator, Airconditioner, Television]}";

$string_to_array = explode("\n", $string);
$data = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($string_to_array); $i++) {
    $data[$i]["key"] = explode("={", $string_to_array[$i])[0];
    $data[$i]["rem"] = explode("rem=", explode(",", $string_to_array[$i])[0])[1];
    $data[$i]["ans"] = rtrim(str_replace("}","",explode("ans=", $string_to_array[$i])[1]), ",");
}
var_dump($data);
```